# How to calculate the sum value of a set of arrays

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

Good day

I was wondering if someone can assist me in calculating the sum value of a array of data.

```
var products = [{'size':'400' },{'size':'500' }] ;

angular.forEach(products, function(item){
   var total = 0;
   total += item.size++;
   return total;
});
```

How do I use $q.all() statement to store up this information as the file download section am using ignores my angular.forEach statment and just checks individual items instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use reduce instead of angular.forEach

`const productSum = products.reduce((sum, product) => sum + parseInt (product.size, 10), 0)`

$q.all is for computing multiple promises. I think you are looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get sum of all sizes then use javascript `reduce` method. It will return the sum of all sizes efficiently.

```js
var products = [{'size':'400' },{'size':'500' }] ;

var sum = products.reduce((a,b) => parseInt(a.size) +  parseInt(b.size))

console.log(sum)
```

About `$q.all`. `$q.all` typically use to send multiple http request one shot. If you want send the sum to your service then bind the sum as data property to one of or all your http requests (depend on your requirement).

Comment: Thanks guys for the update on this. This works perfectly. In regards to the $q.all statement. I thought that would be a better way to get the total as am looping through values but if i use the methods you have suggested I can get the total at the start before I loop through the values.

Comment: Yeah now no need to send multiple requestas. Send the total in one http req